# Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix, : Unexpected CURL error: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: r, virtualbox, h2o, rstudio-server

I am experiencing a persistent error while trying to use H2O's `h2o.automl` function. I am trying to repeatedly run this model. It seems to completely fail after 5 or 10 runs.

```
Error in .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth() : 
  H2O connection has been severed. Cannot connect to instance at http://localhost:54321/
getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

I have updated java in response to: https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/4/docs-website/h2o-docs/faq/r.html (even though I am using a linux virtual machine).
I have added a `h2o.removeall()` and `gc()` in response to [R h2o server CURL error, kind of repeatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360398/r-h2o-server-curl-error-kind-of-repeatable)
I have not attempted any changes regarding memory because my cluster has 16+ GB and the highest reading I have seen is 1.6 GiB in RStudio.

**H2O is running in R/Rstudio Server on an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine. Could the virtual box software be blocking something?**

The details on my H2O cluster are below:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ... Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 896 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster timezone:       America/Chicago 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
    H2O cluster version:        3.35.0.2 
    H2O cluster version age:    19 hours and 24 minutes  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_jholderieath_glq667 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   19.84 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    12 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  12 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I also experienced this issue, although on macOS 12.1.
I tried to debug it and found out that sometimes I also get another error:

```
Unexpected CURL error: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 54321: Connection reset by peer
```

I found out that this issue appears only when I have `RCurl` compiled against `curl` 7.68.0 and above.

Downgrading to `curl` 7.67.0 resolved the issue for me but then I got some issues with RStudio (Segmentation Fault) so I looked into the issue little further.

And I found out that compiling a recent version of `curl` with `--disable-socketpair` solved it for me as well.

I was monitoring open files and sockets (`lsof`) and it seems to me that `R` process runs out of sockets it can create and `RCurl` then fails with one of those errors. Running `gc()` in R frequently helps (I called it after every single request) but still the minimum number of open sockets after `gc()` is slowly but monotonically increasing which leads me to believe there might be some leak. I reported this as a possible bug to the RCurl maintainers.

For anybody using macOS and homebrew this can be accomplished by running the following:

```sh
$ brew edit curl # add --disable-socketpair to args list
$ brew install --build-from-source curl # using reinstall might be needed instead of install

$ export RCURL_PATH="usr/local/opt/curl@7.81.0" # can be found using `brew info curl`
$ export PATH="$RCURL_PATH/bin:$PATH" # for curl-config
$ export LDFLAGS="-L$RCURL_PATH//lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I$RCURL_PATH/include"
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$RCURL_PATH/lib/pkgconfig"

$ R -e "chooseCRANmirror(graphics=FALSE, ind=1);install.packages('RCurl', type = 'source')"
$ R -e "RCurl::curlVersion()$version" # check if RCurl is using the proper version of curl
```

Looking at the `curl` version in ubuntu 20.04 which is 7.68.0 (according to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/curl) I think you won't be able to use the following as the `--disable-socketpair` was added in `curl` 7.73.0 but since you are using a virtual machine it might be easier to just use ubuntu 18.04 since it's [still supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and is using old enough `curl` version (7.58.0).

I haven't used ubuntu for a while but at least I can provide some pseudo-code that should do the same:

```sh
$ sudo apt install devscripts
$ # make sure source repositories are enabled (uncommented in /etc/apt/s
$ apt-get source curl
$ sudo apt-get build-dep curl
$ cd curl
$ nano debian/rules # add the --disable-socketpair configure option
$ dch -i # bump the version
$ debuild -us -uc -b # build the package
$ dpkg -i ../curl-some_version.dpkg

$ export PATH="$RCURL_PATH/bin:$PATH" # for curl-config
$ export LDFLAGS="-L$RCURL_PATH//lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I$RCURL_PATH/include"
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$RCURL_PATH/lib/pkgconfig"

$ R -e "chooseCRANmirror(graphics=FALSE, ind=1);install.packages('RCurl', type = 'source')"
$ R -e "RCurl::curlVersion()$version" # check if RCurl is using the proper version of curl
```